# Acceder a una cadena de JSON con Javascript, Node.JS y Watson

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, ibm-bluemix

Tengo este resultado en JSON que recibo desde IBM Watson:

```
{
  "document_tone": {
    "tones": []
  }
}
```

Este resultado, lo guardo dentro de una variable en Javascript. Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo poner una condición en Javascript, para que cada vez que me llegue ese resultado, en la consola me ponga: "Resultados vacios"?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si a resultados vacíos te refieres por el índice `"tones"` lo puedes hacer así

```
var json = Respuesta_IBM_Watson();
if( json.document_tone.tones.length === 0 ){
   console.log( 'está vacio' );
}

else{
  //Otras cosas
}
```